# Tools to support maintenance jobs with Finder tags

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, finder-tag

When OS X Mavericks was released in 2013 with tagging support built directly into Finder, I expected tagging on OS X to gather steam (at least among “power users”). However, the number of tools and solutions for using tags remains limited:

- [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)’s tag
- [Leap](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/leap/)
- [Yep](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/yep)

I am looking for tools to support maintenance jobs like merging tags, listing tags according to frequency, mass re-tagging.

Are there other tools to help with these jobs?

Comment: AFAIK you would have to write automator scripts to do this now.

Answer (score 1):

[Vitag](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/vitag/), a tool for batch tagging from the command line using your favorite editor, was released by Brett Terpstra yesterday.